# rake does not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I jus created a rails application. I created a model using

```
 ruby script/generate model Article
```

next i edited the my 001_create_articles.rb file by adding these lines in self.up method

```
 def self.up
    create_table :articles do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.text :body
        t.string :published_at
```

```
    t.timestamps
end
```

end

Now i ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

. But migrate does not work, it simply does no print anything. Anyone knows where i am going wrong?

Comment: did you bundle your db gems + edit your database.yml?

Comment: yes i edited my database.yml file and i am sure about the parameters in development section. But wat s bundling gems. sorry am new to rails

Comment: If you're new to rails, I'd recommend you to use rails3 and go straight to railsforzombies.org, you'll learn a lot there.

Comment: What Rails version are you running?

Comment: i am running rails 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing one `end` from your up method?

```
def self.up
  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body
    t.string :published_at
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. But in my file it is present

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to generate a migration. If i understood it right, you added the migration code to the model.

You have to run something like that:

```
ruby script/generate migration articles
```

After that open the generated file and add your code there. Hope it helps

Comment: . sorry tht was again a typo. I hav added the code in 001_create_article.rb and then ran rake. yet no progress :(

Comment: the command prompt blinks for about 3 secs then returns nothing

Comment: i find rake db command is not working in any of my rails projects. will this be a configuration issue?

Comment: yes, that was the command i used.. in all my projects if i give rake db:migrate. it doesn return anything in all the cases. @lucapette